# uninstall from Programs and Features has not enough permissions

Tags: installshield, windows-installer, uninstallation

Win 10.
Installer for application created with Installshield PE 2015.

When I call uninstall by link at Start menu or from Programs and Features control panel started uninstallation.
Unistall call custom script and call some application by cmd call with lower permissions then expected.

Process explorer shows:
started msiexec.exe with full permissions and it is call msiexec.exe with lower permitions, that's not enough for called by csutom action applications.

If uninstaller link *run as Administrator* from start menu - **permissions enough**.

**question:**
Is this a new bug or feature?
What is the meaning of the restriction of rights if uninstallation is already called with maximum permissions on behalf of the administrator?

**note:** application run during uninstallation is strongly requirement for my uninstallation, and for Installshield and uninstaller it is normal to call some custom scripts for this.

Answer (score 0):

This typically indicates you have a bug in your custom action's definition. If it needs elevated permissions, it needs to be scheduled as Deferred in System Context, Commit in System Context, or Rollback in System Context. If you did not do this, and instead relied on the launcher elevating the initial installation context, it can lead to problems like you describe. Try to fix this first by not elevating at the launcher (to reveal the partially latent problems) and then fixing your custom action scheduling.

Occasionally (and I do mean rarely) there is no great alternative to elevating in the launcher. For that case, you may wish to suppress the normal entry in Programs and Features, and create your own that runs an elevating launcher. You may need to manually cache such a launcher on the system, however, as it sounds like you are using a Basic MSI project, and that will cache only the .msi file.